# Error at opening downloaded SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm downloading a database from a website. The downloaded database is called `db.php`
and it's going to be stored at data/data/my.package.name/files under the name `FishingMatey.db`. The database is in the filesystem from the DDMS and I can open it on the PC in SQLite Studio. There my database is filled with the right tables and the right data. Here's my code to download the SQLite database:

```
public boolean downloadDatabase() {
    try {
        // Log.d(TAG, "downloading database");
        URL url = new URL("http://myurl.com/db.php");

        // Open a connection to that URL */
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

        // Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        // Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1)
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        // Convert the Bytes read to a String
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        // Select storage location
        fos = this.context.openFileOutput(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("downloadDatabase", "downloadDatabase Error: ", e);
        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e("downloadDatabase", "downloadDatabase Error: ", e);
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("downloadDatabase", "downloadDatabase Error: ", e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My problem: I can open the database with 
`SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.example.menuswitcher/files/" + DATABASE_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);`, but if I enter `db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_Bewirtschafter, null, null, null, null, null, null);`              I receive the following error:

```
01-08 19:52:22.366: E/AndroidRuntime(6157): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 19:52:22.366: E/AndroidRuntime(6157): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Here's how I call it in the Activity:
        this.b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DBAccess dbAccess = new DBAccess(HauptmenueActivity.this, 1, "FishingMatey.db");
            if (dbAccess.downloadDatabase()) {
                dbAccess.initDatabase();
                Cursor cur = dbAccess.createBewirtschafterAllCursor();
                Log.v("b3", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("name")));
            } else {
                Log.e("b3", "Error!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Does anybody know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

This error means that you forgot to call `cursor.moveToFirst()` before trying to read your Cursor.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_Bewirtschafter, null, null, null, null, null, null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // Do something with the first row, if it exists
}
```